# Get the text only part of an xml node

Tags: xml, scala

Say I have the following piece of xml:

```
<a><b><c>Text for c</c>Text for b</b></a>
```

How do I get just the text for the node alone excluding text for child nodes? i.e.

> a: ""
>
> b: "Text for b"
>
> c: "Text for c"

As the Node.text method includes the the text for any child nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether your child node is atomic one and extract text only from that node:

```
  val xml = <a><b><c>Text for c</c>Text for b</b></a>

  val a = (xml \\ "a")
  val b = (xml \\ "b")
  val c = (xml \\ "c")

  def text(name: String, nodeSeq: NodeSeq) = {
    val text = (for {
      n <- nodeSeq.headOption
      atomNodeText <- n.child.filter(_.isAtom).headOption
    } yield (atomNodeText)) getOrElse("")

    println(name + ": " + text)
  }

  text("a", a)
  text("b", b)
  text("c", c)
```

which produces:

```
a:   
b: Text for b 
c: Text for c
```

Answer (score 0):

In XML a `node` can contain only `childNodes`, and the "text" you are referring is a sequence of nodes of type `Text`. So a solution is to filter it's children of type `Text` and concat them together as a single string, as in method `extractNodeText` below:

```
scala> import scala.xml._
import scala.xml._

scala> def extractNodeText(node: Node) =
     |   node.child.filter(_.isInstanceOf[Text]).map(_.text).mkString("")
extractNodeText: (node: scala.xml.Node)String

scala> val a = XML.loadString("<a><b><c>Text for c</c>Text for b</b></a>")
a: scala.xml.Elem = <a><b><c>Text for c</c>Text for b</b></a>

scala> val aStr = extractNodeText(a)
aStr: String = ""

scala> val b = XML.loadString("<b><c>Text for c</c>Text for b</b>")
b: scala.xml.Elem = <b><c>Text for c</c>Text for b</b>

scala> val bStr = extractNodeText(b)
bStr: String = "Text for b"

scala> val c = XML.loadString(<c>Text for c</c>")
c: scala.xml.Elem = <c>Text for c</c>

scala> val cStr = extractNodeText(c)
cStr: String = "Text for c"
```